# Compare value at t and t-7days

Tags: graphite, grafana

To get some "visual alerting", I'd like to draw simultaneously two curves *on the same graph* in Grafana:

- current time-window graph
- same graph but with 7 days ago data

The idea is to be able to compare data evolution on the same day in the previous week.

I could not find a Graphite function for that (but I may have missed something in the doc).

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [timeShift](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.timeShift) to make a metric in grafana with your series shifted back a week.

This kind of thing is also a good application for [series-specific display overrides](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/graph/#series-specific-overrides) in grafana, so you can make the shifted series display differently from the current data.